# NoReverseMatch at error - Issue in my HTML url

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

When I click my edit button (which is on a page called profile.html) I'm getting NoReverseMatch at /profile/singingstarz
Reverse for 'edit_post' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edit_post/(?P[^/]+)/$']

The issue is one line inside my html but I can't figure out what it should be:

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'edit_post' post.id %}">View</a>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("make_post", views.make_post, name="make_post"),
    path('edit_post/<str:pk>/', views.edit_post, name="edit_post"),
    path("profile/<str:username>", views.profile, name="profile"),
    ]
```

my view currently, but I've tried many different views. The issue is in the html part because when I take it out, the profile page loads totally fine.

```
@login_required
@csrf_exempt
def edit_post(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        post_id = request.POST.get('id')
        new_post = request.POST.get('text')
        try:
     
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
            if post.username == request.user:
                post.text = new_post.strip()
               
                post.save()
                return JsonResponse({}, status=201)
        except:
            return JsonResponse({}, status=404)

    return JsonResponse({}, status=400)
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Post(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    username = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    related_name='author', 
    null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)      
    like = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,  blank=True, related_name="liked_user")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username.username #used to be .user.username
```

Comment: check the post, either there is a typo or there is no objects that is being passed into the template... try printing out the queryset you are sending into the template and make sure it is not none

Comment: <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'edit_post' post.id %}">View</a> in this line post.id is not having any value kindly check the view from where you are passing this post in context.